# Is there a simpler/ more concise way to initialize this array in Lua?

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

I have the following logic:

```
delete_request = {}
delete_request.value = {}
delete_request.value.username = {}
delete_request.value.username.value = rowvm.userid
```

I'd like to know if there's an easier way to initialize an array with this type of a structure... or if what I have is the best way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
delete_request = {value = {username = {value = rowvm.userid}}}
```